# how can I get leakage current in tlp?

Tags: transmission-line, esd, bias, leakage-current

I got tlp test data and found that the current at vertical line means leakage current.

But I don't understand the method how does the tlp-test measure the leakage current.

I tried to search the method, but I failed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The wavy VI curve is leakage but when Vmax is exceeded with sufficient time (ns) , then abrupt avalanche failure occurs followed by a short circuit with the max current dropping down vertically to 0V

These were tested with a fancy tester.
https://assets.thermofisher.com/TFS-Assets/CAD/Specification-Sheets/Celestron-Spec-Sheet-0215.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In a simple google search for {esd tlp leakage current} the third hit "[What is TLP? - Barth Electronics](https://barthelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/What-is-TLP.pdf)" gives sufficient explanation on how the TLP - Transmission Line Pulse testing - is done. In part, the appnote says:

> TLP testing is done by applying the rectangular test pulse to the two
>   pins of the Device Under Test (DUT) to be tested. The most common
>   method of introducing the pulse to the DUT has been to split the pulse
>   between a grounded 56-ohm resistor and a 500 to 1500 ohm resistor in
>   series with the DUT pin to be tested. The common pin is connected to
>   the ground lead to provide a return path for the pulse current.

See also this [EDN article, TLP-testing-gains-momentum](https://www.edn.com/design/test-and-measurement/4378571/TLP-testing-gains-momentum), which explains how TLP differs from more common ESD testing.